# PHP : 2 action in 1 form

Tags: php, html

i just want to pass the data in 2 different action . 1st action is to pass the data into the database and 2nd action is to open new tab. i already try my self by adding  2 action in 1 form but its not working at all, and tried to search in other site but they direct the problem to AJAX. is there any way to make 2 action and 1 form w/out using AJAX?

Comment: You can using javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one action in a new tab where you insert the data

In your form

```
<form action="action.php" method="get" target="_blank">
```

target="_blank" to open action in a new tab

action.php

```
$data = $_GET["data"];
mysql_query("insert ".$data);

header('Location: yourpage.php');
```

header redirected to the page you want
or you can write your code after the insert